# Matching two strings on different lines with tabs using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following two strings and would like to search for when they occur, I'm struggling as they are on different lines with a tab within the HTML file I'm using.

```
<span class="price">$17.95</span> 




    <span class="supersaver">
```

This is what I have tried so far, the value of the price can change, I have tried with just \s+  by itself and also with a combination \n+\t+ etc..

```
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(file, @"<span class=""price"">[$]\d+[.]\d+</span>\n+\t+<span class=""supersaver"">",
                    RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

I've added the quotes in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(file, @"<span class=price>[$]\d+[.]\d+</span>[\s\n\t.]+<span class=supersaver>",
                RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

your solution had to have one or more spaces followed by tabs and no line, the regex above should match any of them.

Comment: @Paul - There is no literal `.` between </span> and <span .. >

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing some quotes there. If your going to use regex, maybe a more general one might work better.

```
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(file, @"<span\s+class\s*=\s*""price""\s*>\$\d*\.\d*</span\s*>\s*<span\s+class\s*=\s*""supersaver""\s*>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: This only works if you replace \" with "" around price and suppersaver.. in C#